# how to prevent div element to move while scrolling (without use fixed position)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, scrollbar

I want to prevent the div move when I'm scrolling down/up.
but the reason that I don't want the position:fixed property it's because when the element is fixed
the scroll bar is off. for example

```
div{
    position:fixed;
    top:1500px;
}
```

you can't reach this element with scroll because it's fixed and scroll bar disappear.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qh9ef9ga/
u can see in this fiddle that there is a div in 1000px down but u cant reach to him by scrolling.

for more to understand why i need it:
http://parralaxtest.azurewebsites.net/

enter this link , u can see my code (f12 chrome) in this case the elements that move are fixed.
the problem is that when u change screen size the scroll bar are changed and make you able to change the top position of the sun for example. if u get a big screen the sun will not arrived when scroll down.

thanks for help.

Comment: browsers don't support sticky yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: My CSS are not recognize this option.

Comment: @RefaelOknin your css recognize it, but your browser does not support it))

Comment: You'll need to provide us with a little more than your code snippet for us to be able to help you. Could write a new fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

After see the code the only thing pop up in my mind is that you are using px and percentage at the same time means few things are defined in percentage while others are in px. that's why on changing screen size object with percentage changes their size but other object with px does not.

change fixed with absolute